# Question of browser performance and using Bodymovin and CSS animations

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, css-animations, bodymovin

I am in the process of building a website full of SVG illustrations that have animated components that are being animated with [Bodymovin](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-web).

But the backgrounds are also sometimes animating to show movement (a runner SVG with his arms & legs moving and a background SVG moving right to left showing progress).

Am I right in trying to limit using Bodymovin to the complex animations for the characters so I can use CSS transform3d animations for the simple background movements?

I'm trying to make things animate smoothly whilst being easy on everyone's browsers!

I would usually install GSAP and animate stuff with that, but that would mean adding a second JS animations library for the backgrounds as the client has a designer generating the Bodymovin animations.

Any advice would be welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Bodymovin appears to be lagging with multiple animations on a page, so I ended up animating the backgrounds with CSS animations to keep the browsers' workload to a minimum.

And through animating translate3d, the css animations were smooth, too.